# trouble with arduino standalone circuit and xbee

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have an application that sends data from 1 XBee connected to a computer to another Xbee connected to a microprocessor(ATMEGA328P-PU). I programmed the program into the microprocessor using a arduino board and everything work as programmed on the board itself. However, when brought over to connect everything on the breadboard, it is not working as programmed. I tried loading the microprocessor with a simple blink led program and it works on the breadboard. What is wrong?

What I've connected to the microprocessor on the breadboard: pull up resistor between pin 1 and vcc DataOut and DataIn to rx and tx of microprocessor VCC to pin 7,20 and 21. Gnd to 8 and 22 20Mhz crystal with 2 22pF capacitors to pin 9 and 10.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is your energy supply on the breadboard? Schematics of the breadboard ATMEGA/ XBee combination would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem lies with the frequency of the crystal. Arduino board uses 16 Mhz I'm using 20Mhz and thus the data rate between the two device is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Xbee modules in particular but with RF modules in general make sure you have some decoupling caps near the power supply for the module, maybe try a 10uF and 0.1uF in parallel. I also found the following list of common XBee mistakes that may be useful:

http://www.faludi.com/projects/common-xbee-mistakes/

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem lies with the frequency of the crystal. Arduino board uses 16 Mhz I'm using 20Mhz and thus the data rate between the two device is incorrect.

Comment: @cwh Why not write an answer explaining how you fixed it?